# Find the derivative of $f(w) = (5w^2 + 3)e^{w^2}$

Tags: calculus

Could you please explain step by step. I tried using the chain rule on this but then i tried using the product rule. I'm really lost here.

Comment: There really isn't anything else to it, but mechanical application of the rules you named. Please include the steps you've done so far. If you do so, people will be happy to advise you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a deep breath

$f (w)= (5w^2+3)*e^{w^2} $

So by the product rule;

$f'(w)=(5w^2+3)'e^{w^2} + (5w^2+3)(e^{w^2})'$

$(5w^2+3)'$ is easy to find.  It is $10w $

we need the chain rule to find $(e^{w^2})'$.  $(e^x)'= e^x$ so $(e^{w^2})'= e^{w^2}*(
w^2)'=e^{w^2}*2w $

So $f'(w)=10w*e^{w^2}+(5w^2+3)*e^{w^2}*2w $.

We can then factor and get $f'(x)=2w*e^{w^2}[5 + 5w^2+3]=2we^{w^2 }(8+5w^2) $

Answer (score 0):

$f^{'}(w)=10w e^{w^2}$+$2w.e^{w^2}(5w^2+3)$

By using $\frac{d(ab)}{x}=a\frac{db}{dx}+b\frac{da}{dx}$

and $\frac{d(e^{w^2})}{dw}=2w.e^{w^2}$

Answer (score 0):

You also could have used logarithmic differentiation
$$y= (5w^2+3)\,e^{w^2}\implies \log(y)=\log(5w^2+3)+w^2$$ Diffrentiate both sides $$\frac{y'}y=\frac {10w}{5w^2+3}+2w=\frac{2 w \left(5 w^2+8\right)}{5w^2+3}$$ $$y'=y\frac{y'}y=(5w^2+3)\,e^{w^2}\frac{2 w \left(5 w^2+8\right)}{5w^2+3}=2 w \left(5 w^2+8\right)\,e^{w^2}$$